# Tic Tac Toe game in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am a newbie in programming.

for practice, I am trying to make Tic Tac Toe game in kotlin.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nVSYkQoV5I&t=600s

I have referred to upper YouTube link.

but that link is for java. Anyway, i got trouble.

My code is below.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var round = 0
    var player1turn = true
    var playerpoints = 0
    var p1Text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.p1textview)
    var p2Text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.p2textview)
    lateinit var buttonLists:Array<Array<Button>>


// this for loop doesn't execute
    for (i in 0..3) {
        for (j in 0..3) {
            var buttonID = "button_" + i + j
            var resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID,"id", getPackageName())
            buttonLists[i][j] = findViewById(resourceID)
            buttonLists[i][j].setOnClickListener{
                buttonLists[i][j].text = "X"
            })
        }
    }
}
```

in the AVD, it is not excuted.
what's problem in my code?

Comment: You need to describe your question a bit better than that :) For example, can you please share here the logs? You are probably having some error and you can see that in the console

Comment: Oh, Thank You. I got solution from your answer. lateinit was problem. I apologize for my question. I have to write more informations.